# Why Does User Account Setting Disturbs Admin Page of My Site In My Computer

Tags: xampp

Why does this message from XAMPP disturbs the administrator page of website?

> Important!
>
> Because an activated User Account Control (UAC) on your system some functions of XAMPP are possibly restricted. With UAC please avoid to install XAMPP to C:\Program Files (x86) (missing write permissions). Or deactivate UAC with msconfig after this setup.

Comment: Think about this: if you were answering this question, would you instantly leave because it's formatted badly and lacks information, or would you try to work out what the OP is trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the advice in the message!

Install XAMPP in a directory not protected by UAC, so not in `C:\Program Files (x86)`, `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Windows`. As an example you could use `C:\xampp`.